# Adobe Flash Builder : AddChild vs AddElement

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

Using Adobe Flash Builder 4.0 ?

Getting error when using addChild(). Compiler suggests about using addElement(). Are both these functions alternate of each other ? Or is it like addChild is deprecated ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get clear. Adobe Flash Builder is IDE for developing flex apps. What's important is Flex SDK version. Obviously you're using version 4+. I suggest to avoid using mx (Flex 3) components without strong need. You should read more about Flex 3 and Flex 4 difference.

Post about [addChild vs addElement](http://www.billdwhite.com/wordpress/?p=296).